# EXCEL VBA - LOOP error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to run a particular function, I tested this yesterday and it works. I wanted this looped but when excel tries the same function for the next row, I get a file path error.

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub odoc()

Dim fpath As String
Dim objWord As Object
Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
fpath = Application.ActiveCell.Value
Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
objWord.Documents.Open (fpath)
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Application.Run MacroName:="CopySAM"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
objWord.Application.Quit
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -14).Select
Next cel

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: on which line do you get an error and what is the exact error message? Also, try to avoid using ActiveCell/Activesheet references where possible and use names e.g. loop a range held in a variable or work with a sheet by name.

Comment: `fpath` is set outside the loop and so never changes?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do here. Every cell in the range contains a filepath? If so, you'd want `objWord.Documents.Open(cel.value)` in your loop. Right now, it looks like it's opening the same word document over and over.

Comment: @QHarr - I get Runtime error '-2147417848 (80010108) Automation Error - The Object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Comment: SJR & user1266 - Thank you so much for feedback, I will try this now and update if it works. thanks again. Yes so the cell contains a filepath from which I need certain information within the Word table. And then it simply splits it on to excel.

Comment: @JohnInk I get the same error if use    objWord.Documents.Open(cel.value)

Comment: That error is because you quit the application at the end of your loop with `objWord.Application.Quit`. The next time the loop comes around, Word is no longer open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tidies up your loop - it should now work. Though I have to say there are better ways to paste the data than the way you're using..

```
Sub odoc()

    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Documents.Open (cel)
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Application.Run MacroName:="CopySAM"
        cel.Offset(0, 14).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        objWord.Application.Quit
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much - this works now. I cant believe it I was thinking all this time about this. You mentioned a better approach to this, I not very good at VBA so my approach my very noob. how would you suggest I should have approached this.

Comment: You could replace the two lines: `cel.Offset(0, 14).Select` and `ActiveSheet.Paste` with one line: `cel.Offset(0, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` for instance.

Comment: Also, instead of creating your Word.Application and killing it repeatedly, you could create it outside the loop and kill it after the loop finishes by within the loop closing the document, rather than quitting Word itself. I think it's something like  `objWord.ActiveDocument.Close` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for this, It works so much faster now also.

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark it answered.